# how to destroy this. Python tk

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I got the question about this. 
I am new learner on Python tk. Usually it use

```
class myApp :
def __init__(self, gui,) :
self.root = gui
```

Then destroy it by

```
self.root.destroy()
```

But I got this code, how could I destroy this window

```
from travelToolbox import readItems, readTransactions
import tkinter as tk

class myApp(tk.Tk): 
    def __init__(self, itemRecords) :
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.itemRecords = itemRecords
        self.grid()
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.entry.grid(column=1,row=0)
        button1 = tk.Button(self,text="Show",command=self.showStockItem)
        button1.grid(column=2,row=0)
        button2 = tk.Button(self,text="Quit",command=self.quitit)
        button2.grid(column=1,row=1)
        label = tk.Label(self, anchor="w", text='Item ID')
        label.grid(column=0,row=0)
```

I tried destroy but I get back with

```
AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'root'
```

Please help me with this. Thank you so much.

Comment: Why would you want to destroy the root window?

Comment: Close this window

Comment: Programmatically? But Why? Usually the main window is closed by the user.

Answer (score 3):

Since `MyApp` inherits from `tk.Tk`, you can call `destroy()` on `self`.
Maybe something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk


class MyApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        tk.Button(self, text='quit', command=self.quit).pack()
        self.mainloop()

    def quit(self):
        self.destroy()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    MyApp()
```